# How do I wrap this C function, with multiple arguments, with ctypes?

Tags: python, arrays, pointers, return, ctypes

I have the function prototype here:

```
extern "C" void __stdcall__declspec(dllexport) ReturnPulse(double*,double*,double*,double*,double*);
```

I need to write some python to access this function that is in a DLL.
I have loaded the DLL, but
each of the double* is actually pointing to a variable number of doubles (an array), and
I'm having trouble getting it to function properly.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an array with, say, `n` doubles:

```
arr7 = ctypes.c_double * `n` 
x = arr7()
```

and pass `x` to your function where it wants a `double*`.  Or if you need to initialize `x` as you make it:

```
x = arr7(i*0.1 for i in xrange(7))
```

and the like.  You can loop over `x`, index it, and so on.

Comment: You're welcome; if this answer proves to be the solution to your problem, remember to accept it (use the checkmark icon under the number giving up/down vote count for the answer), that's fundamental SO etiquette.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at ctypes too much, but try using a numpy array of the right type. If that doesn't just automatically work, they also have a ctypes attribute that should contain a pointer to the data.