# "exception: access violation writing" error in Python (ctypes)

Tags: python, activex, autocad, comtypes

I've been learning python (2.7) for a couple of weeks to be able to automatise autocad, so, be patient I'm python noob.

I'm trying to get the attributes of a newely created block to modify them, the [doc](http://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/AutoCAD-ActiveX/files/GUID-3E8E1756-F45D-4CCE-838B-00FBC0374278-htm.html) says that in VBA it would be:

```
Set blockRefObj = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.InsertBlock(insertionPnt, "TESTBLOCK", 1#, 1#, 1#, 0)
varAttributes = blockRefObj.GetAttributes
For I = LBound(varAttributes) To UBound(varAttributes)
    strAttributes = strAttributes & vbLf & "  Tag: " & varAttributes(I).TagString & _
        vbLf & "  Value: " & varAttributes(I).TextString & vbLf & "    "
```

I've been translating several snippets of VBA code to Python code and it worked every time, but for this one, I'm trying:

```
acad = comtypes.client.GetActiveObject("AutoCAD.Application")
doc = acad.ActiveDocument
ms = doc.ModelSpace
myBlock = ms.InsertBlock(array.array('d', [0, 0, 0]), 'TESTBLOCK', 1, 1, 1, 0)
varAttributes = myBlock.getAttributes()
for i in varAttributes:
    print i
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Ab******/test3/abtro2.py", line 84, in <module>
    add_PB(pt[0], pt[1], PB, int(ELR), PB_type, type_PEO, int(sorties), PB_addr[float(re.sub('PB', '', PB))])
  File "C:/Ab******/test3/abtro2.py", line 33, in add_PB
    varAttributes = myPB_Block.getAttributes()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\comtypes\automation.py", line 506, in __ctypes_from_outparam__
    result = self.value
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\comtypes\automation.py", line 457, in _get_value
    typ = _vartype_to_ctype[self.vt & ~VT_ARRAY]
KeyError: 9
Exception WindowsError: 'exception: access violation writing 0x005608A4' in  ignored
```

From what I read from the VBA snippet, `getAttributes` method must return an array, so my question is twofold:

1. <strike>Is using `.getAttributes` and `.getAttributes()` the same thing in python?</strike> **noob question**
2. Why the ActiveX method used in Python does not give the same result (an array) as in VBA?

**EDIT**
From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382076/windowserror-exception-access-violation-ctypes-question) I understand that perhaps Python is:

> performing illegal operations (the kind of operations that if went
>   unchecked would probably crash your system).

From the doc, the kind of array returned is:

> Type: Variant (array of AttributeReference objects)

So, perhaps it's because it's not a simple array, but an array of objects that is returned, does somebody knows how to circumvent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/comtypes/mailman/comtypes-users/?viewmonth=200808&page=1):

You have to uncomment two line, for me it's 862 and 863 in Python27\Lib\site-packages\comtypes\automation.py then it works with `getAttributes()`